# Embeddings into a Hausdorff space are proper?

Tags: general-topology

I am sure I am missing something obvious here, but I cannot resolve the following (presumably apparent) contradiction. In the book "Topological manifold" by John Lee, 2nd edition, proposition 4.93,  some sufficient conditions for a map to be proper are stated. Condition (e) is

Let $F:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map, $Y$ a Hausdorff space. If $F$ has a continuous left inverse than $F$ is proper.

It seems to me that since $F$ is continuous with left continuous inverse it is a topological embedding. But then wouldn't the example mentioned here

[Embeddings are precisely proper injective immersions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116124/embeddings-are-precisely-proper-injective-immersions)

of the embedding of an open disk (with subspace topology) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be a counterexample as the inclusion is not proper? (e.g. the inverse image of the closed disk is the open disk).

In fact condition (d) of proposition 4.93 says that *closed* embeddings are proper.

Comment: What is the supposed continuous left inverse $g\colon \mathbb R^2\to D$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_D$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Your comment make me think I was wrong in assuming the inclusion $f$ to be a topological embedding. However in order for $f$ to be a topological embedding isn't enough that $U\subset D$ is open if and only if $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which holds $D$ being open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @GFR: You're ignoring one of the assumptions, which is that $F$ has a left inverse. $F$ being an embedding is not enough to guarantee the existence of a left inverse, which is what Hagen is pointing out.

Comment: Thanks, my confusion was indeed because I did not realise that an embedding does not necessarily have a left inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing some implications with their converses. My condition (e) says **if** $F$ has a continuous left inverse, **then** $F$ is proper. It's also true in that case that $F$ is a topological embedding (see Problem 3-13 in the same book). However, neither of those implications is reversible. There exist nonproper embeddings that have no continuous left inverse (such as the embedding of an open disk into $\mathbb R^2$ that you mentioned), and there exist proper embeddings that have no continuous left inverse (such as the embedding of the unit circle into $\mathbb R^2$). There's no contradiction.