# troubles to understand the embedding theorem

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I try to understand the proof of the embedding theorem:

"An $m-$dimensional differentiable manifold can be embedded as a closed subset of the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$, if $2m<n$."

The proof is given as follow: We know that we can find for a manifold a proper function $f:M^m \to \Bbb R^n$ for an $n>0$ and that we can approximate this by an injective immersion $g:M^m \to \Bbb R^n$, so that $\vert g - f \vert \leq 1$ and $A= \emptyset$. If $K \subset \Bbb R^n$ is compact, then $K \subset K(r)$ for some radius $r$, hence $g^{-1}(K)$ is closed in the compact set $f^{-1}(K\overline{(r+1)})$, hence compact. Therefore $g$ is proper, hence an embedding.

Now I have some questions in this proof:

1. Why we have that if $K \subset \Bbb R^n$ is compact, then $K \subset K(r)$ for some radius $r$?
2. Why it follows that $g^{-1}(K)$ is closed in the compact set $f^{-1}(K\overline{(r+1)})$?
3. Why we can now conclude that a proper is an embedding?

EDIT:

4. I guess, he claims that $g^{-1}(K) \subset f^{-1}(K\overline{(r+1)})$ to conclude that $g^{-1}(K)$ is compact. But Why is this inclusion right? I guess that it comes from the fact, that $\vert g - f \vert \leq 1$. But I am not sure.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are bounded.
2. Preimage of a closed set by continuous $g$ is closed, and preimage of a compact set  by proper $f$ is compact.
3. Proper injective immersion [is exactly an embedding with closed image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116124/embeddings-are-precisely-proper-injective-immersions).
4. $g^{-1}(K)\subseteq f^{-1}(K(r+1))$ if and only if $[g(x)\in K\implies f(x)\in K(r+1)]$. But $g(x)\in K\implies g(x)\in K(r)$ i.e. $|g(x)|<r$ and by triangle inequality $|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|+|f(x)-g(x)|<r+1$, so indeed $[g(x)\in K\implies f(x)\in K(r+1)]$. Thus $g^{-1}(K)\subseteq f^{-1}(K(r+1))$ and $g^{-1}(K)\subset f^{-1}(\overline{K(r+1)})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I have no one more question, that I wrote as EDIT above.

Comment: See the edit. I notice that you have not upvoted or accepted any of the answers to any of your previous questions. People may be more motivated to answer in the future if you do so.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. :) If you are motivated maybe you can help me here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914361/help-to-understand-the-proof-about-injective-immersions  I would be verry happy.

Comment: It's not just about me, but more about all the answers you get. Accepting the answer also removes the question from the "unanswered" queue, which helps declutter the site.