# Help to understand the proof about injective immersions

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm currently working on the proof of the following theorem in the book of "Bröcker":

Let $M^m$ be a differential manifold and $f:M^m \to \Bbb R^n$ be a differentiable map and $2m < n$. Let $A \subset M$ be closed and let the restriction of $f$ to a neighbourhood $U$ of $A$ be an injective immersion. Then arbitrarily close of $f$ there exists an injective immersion $g: M^m \to \Bbb R^n$, s.t. $g \vert A = f \vert A$.

The proof is given as follow:

[image]

I don't understand here why, we have that $g_v$ are still immersions?

Also later, he used the Sard theorem to implies that the image of this map has measure zero. So we may choose $b_v$ not to be in this image.. I don't understand how he used here the theorem and how he can conclude that.

EDIT:
[image]

Here is the Lemma 7.6 but I don't see the relation.

Many thanks for some help.

Answer (score 1):

First, if $g_\nu$ has rank $m=\dim M$, then that means the map is an immersion.

Second, a set of measure $0$ has empty interior, and so the complement is dense. It certain follows that the complement is non-empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why they have rank $m$? I don't see how we conclude this

Comment: Ah, your question was misleading. It follows from 7.6 because he's taking the $g_\nu$ to be sufficiently small perturbations of an immersion. (To understand why 7.6 holds, think about continuity of the determinant function. If some $m\times m$ minor of the derivative matrix is nonsingular, then you can vary the map in an open set keeping that minor nonsingular. All you need for this is $C^1$-closeness, not $C^\infty$-closeness.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, indeed my question was misleading. Just for the second point, a set of measure 0 has an empty interior? I never saw this conclusion? How we get this?

Comment: Because a rectangle in $\Bbb R^n$ or ball in $\Bbb R^n$ cannot have measure $0$. If you want a proof, see the appendix of Guiillemin & Pollack's Differential Topology book.

Comment: Okay makes sense. (Thanks for your patience). But still I am blocked: Let's have $k:N^{2m} \to \Bbb R^n$ be the map in the proof. So we have that $k(N^{2m}$ is not empty and we choose the $b_v \notin k(N^{2m}$. But why we do this and how he continue his proof? I am sorry to ask you so much questions but I find this a really hard proof....

Comment: He does this to insure that $g_\nu$ (inductively constructed) will be one-to-one. And you can choose the vector $b_\nu$ as close to $0$ as desired (so that the perturbation will be small). ... You might find it helpful to read Guillemin & Pollack; I don't know the text you're reading, but I taught many undergraduates out of G&P and it's accessible.