# Appropriate basis for the differential of the flow using the Poincaré map

Tags: dynamical-systems

**Statement**: Given $P:\Sigma\cap U\rightarrow \Sigma\cap U'$ a Poincaré map related to a T-periodic orbit $\gamma = \left \{ \varphi (t,p) : t\in [0,T] \right \}$ of a vector field $X:W=\overset{\circ}{W}\subset\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n; \: C^r, \:r\geq 1$. Show that in an appropriate basis:

[image]

where $\tau (q)$ is the returning time for $q\in \Sigma\cap U$.

**First approach**: I see that the first column is for the eigenvalue 1 that has eigenvector X(p) because: $X(p) = X(\varphi(t,p))_{\mid t = 0} = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\varphi(T,\varphi(t,p))_{\mid t = 0} = D\varphi(T,\varphi(t,p))\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}\varphi(t,p)_{\mid t = 0}=D\varphi(T,p)\cdot X(p).$

But now, I don't know what to do with the other part of the matrix. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: You should use the flow box theorem. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263504/particular-function-in-proof-of-flow-box-theorem