# A smooth vector field of a differentiable manifold represented by $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ under some coordinate chart

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Suppose V is a smooth vector field of a differentiable manifold $\mathcal{M}$, and let $p\in \mathcal{M}$, we know that with some coordinate chart $(U,\phi)$, V can be represented by $V=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ for some smooth function $a^{i}$ on $\phi (U)$. My question is, can we choose a special coordinate chart such that $V=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true if and only if the vector field does not vanish at $p$. This is sometimes called the flow box theorem or the straightening theorem, or the rectification theorem. This is proven in most textbooks on ordinary differential equations, such as Arnol'd, *Ordinary Differential Equations.*

Some hints can be found in this question.
[Particular function in proof of flow box theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263504/particular-function-in-proof-of-flow-box-theorem)