# Question about properly discontinuous actions in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, group-actions, topological-groups

I was reading the Katok's book on *Fuchsian groups* and I read that she asserts the following:

> It is clear from the definition that $G$ acts properly and discontinuously on $X$ if and only if each orbit is discrete and the order of the stabilizer of each point is finite.

I am trying to show that if each orbit is discrete and the order of the stabilizer of each point is finite, then $G$ acts properly and discontinuously on $X.$

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183326/katoks-fuchsian-groups-properly-discontinuous-action-homeomorphisms-vs-isome?rq=1) SE discussion there's an answer that apparently show this fact using the following argument:

> Consider a compact $K\subset X, x\in X$ and the subset $K_x=K\cap Gx.$ Then $K_x$ is a discrete **closed** subspace of a compact space. But every discrete closed subspace of a compact space is finite.

I am really stuck in proving that $K_x$ must be a closed subspace of $X.$ I tried to do this by showing that $Gx$ is a closed subset of $X$ (because if then, we would have that $K\cap G_x$ is a closed subset of $X$ contained in the compact space $K$), but I only achieve this by assuming that $G$ is a group of **isometries** instead of **homeomorphisms**. Is this true if we only assume that $G$ is as group of homeomorphisms? (the OP on the link cited above asserts that he could prove this fact only assuming that $G$ is a group of homeomorphisms of $X$). How can I prove it if so? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** There are several discussions on SE concluding that Katok refers in general to isometries groups, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3377450/a-group-acts-properly-discontinuously-on-x-if-and-only-if-each-orbit-is-discre); but this particular SE discussion do not adress the question of wheter is true that $Gx\cap K$ is always closed or not (I think that the example $\{1/n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ may not be a counterexample because I don't know if this can be an orbit of a point by a group acting by homeomorphisms on $X$).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you should spell out precisely which definition of proper discontinuity you are using (referring instead to Katok is suboptimal since not everybody has this book). Include the assumptions that you are making on $X$. (Do you assume metrizable, as Katok does? Anything else, like local compactness?)

Comment: Lastly, if you read my linked answer, definition D2 there (and, hence, Proposition 2) **assumes** that the orbit is closed and discrete.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first spell out definitions and your question:

Suppose that $X$ is a metrizable topological space. For $G<Homeo(X)$ and $x\in X$, the subgroup $G_x=\{g\in G: gx=x\}$ is called the *$G$-stabilizer* of $x$.

A subgroup $G< Homeo(X)$ is said to be "properly discontinuous" (in Katok's sense) if for every compact $K\subset X$ and every $x\in X$ the subset
$$
\{g\in G: gx\in K\}\subset G
$$
is finite. This condition combines two properties: (a) finiteness of $G$-stabilizers of points in $X$, (b) the condition that every $G$-orbit in $X$ has no accumulation points in $X$. Moreover, (a) & (b) imply proper discontinuity in Katok's sense. (See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183326/katoks-fuchsian-groups-properly-discontinuous-action-homeomorphisms-vs-isome?rq=1).)

**Your question:** Suppose that $X$ is a metrizable space, $G<Homeo(X)$ is a subgroup such that for (i) all point-stabilizers $G_x<G$ are finite, and (ii) for every $x\in X$ the orbit $Gx\subset X$ is discrete (i.e. is a discrete space with respect to the subspace topology). Does it follow that $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $X$ in Katok's sense? Equivalently, does it follow that each $G$-orbit is closed in $X$?

I will show that the answer is negative. My example, in fact, will be coming from Fuchsian groups. Let $S$ be a orientable compact hyperbolic surface, $G< PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$ a discrete (Fuchsian) subgroup such that ${\mathbb H}^2/G$ is isometric to $S$. It is known that in this case every point of the boundary circle of the hyperbolic plane ${\mathbb H}^2$ is a **point of approximation** or, equivalently, **conical limit point** of the $G$-action on ${\mathbb H}^2$. See for instance Theorem 12.4.5 in

*Ratcliffe, John G.*, [**Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-31597-9), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 149. Cham: Springer (ISBN 978-3-030-31596-2/hbk; 978-3-030-31597-9/ebook). xii, 800 p. (2019). [ZBL1430.51002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1430.51002).

A better place to read this staff is in

*Bowditch, B. H.*, [**Geometrical finiteness for hyperbolic groups**](https://doi.org/10.1006/jfan.1993.1052), J. Funct. Anal. 113, No. 2, 245-317 (1993). [ZBL0789.57007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0789.57007).

Here is the definition of "conical" (you can also find it in the above references):

Let $Z={\mathbb H}^2\sqcup S^1$ (where $S^1$ is the boundary circle of the hyperbolic plane). The **$r$-conical topology** $T_r$ (where $r>0$) on $Z$ is defined (via its basis) as follows: For points $z\in {\mathbb H}^2$ the topology is standard, the basis at $z$ consists of open disks $B(z,R)=\{x\in {\mathbb H}^2: d(x,z)<R\}$, where $R>0$ and $d$ denotes the hyperbolic metric. For points $z\in S^1$ the basis consists of the following subsets:
$$
C(z, \rho, r)=\{z\}\cup N_r(\rho),
$$
where $\rho\subset {\mathbb H}^2$ are hyperbolic rays  asymptotic to $z$ and $N_r$ denotes the open $r$-neighborhood of $\rho$ in ${\mathbb H}^2$ with respect to the hyperbolic metric $d$ (the number $r$ is fixed as above). The terminology "conical" comes from the fact that if $\rho$ happens to be a Euclidean line segment $oz$ (in the unit disk model), connecting the center of the unit disk to $z$, then, apart from a bounded subset of ${\mathbb H}^2$, $N_r(\rho)$ is a Euclidean cone with the axis $oz$.

In any case, this basis generates a topology, denoted $T_r$, on $Z$. This is not the standard topology homeomorphic to the closed unit disk. In this topology, $S^1$ (with the subspace topology) is a discrete space, since for each $z\in S^1$, $C(z, \rho, r)\cap S^1=\{z\}$, i.e. $\{z\}$ is open in $S^1$.

Now, every group $G$ of hyperbolic isometries acts on $Z$ by homeomorphisms (where the action on the boundary circle is the standard one): In fact, $G$ preserves the above basis of topology on $Z$. Furthermore, $(Z, T_r)$ is Hausdorff for all $r>0$. The only mildly nontrivial case to consider is of $z_1\ne z_2\in S^1$. Take two rays $oz_i$ asymptotic to $z_i$ (still, the  unit disk model) and remove from both some nonempty initial subsegments; the result are rays $\rho_i=x_i z_i$, $x_i\in oz_i$, $x_i\ne o$. Then
$$
C(z_1, \rho_1, r)\cap C(z_2, \rho_2, r)=\emptyset , 
$$
provided that $d(x_i,o)$ are large enough.

With a bit more work, one proves that for every $r>0$, $(Z,T_r)$ is a **regular** topological space, i.e. for each $z\in Z$ and a closed subset $F\subset Z\setminus \{z\}$, there are disjoint open neighborhoods $U(z), U(F)$ of $z, F$ in $(Z,T_r)$. The most interesting case is when $z\in S^1, F\subset S^1$. Let me know if you have trouble proving regularity.

**Remark.** Even though it is not needed, each space $(Z,T_r)$ is locally compact.

Let $z\in S^1$ be a point not fixed by any nontrivial element of $G$ (the set of fixed points is countable, hence, such $z$ always exists). Lastly, set
$$
X:= {\mathbb H}^2 \cup Gz \subset Z,
$$
equipped with the subspace topology induced from $T_r$ ($X$ is open in $Z$ with respect to $T_r$). The space $X$ is easily seen to be 2nd countable; it is also Hausdorff and regular as a subspace of Hausdorff and regular space $Z$. Hence, Urysohn's metrization theorem  implies that $X$ is metrizable.

The point $z$ is an $r$-conical limit point of every $G$-orbit $Gx\subset {\mathbb H}^2$, meaning that there exists $r>0$ and a sequence $g_n\in G$ such that $g_nx\to z$ in the topology $T_r$. (This is the content of the theorem quoted above.) Thus, the orbit $Gx$ is discrete but not closed in $(X,T_r)$. For each $y\in Gz$, orbit $Gy$ is contained in $S^1$ and, hence, is discrete. Thus, every $G$-orbit in $(X,T_r)$ is discrete. At the same time, the $G$-stabilizer of every point in $X$ is trivial. Putting it all together, we obtain the required example: $G< Homeo(X, T_r)$ is a subgroup satisfying (i) and (ii) but not acting properly discontinuously in Katok's sense. What is it good for, I do not know.

Comment: Sorry for not answering before, I am trying to fully understand your answer. Can I think about $Z$ as $\mathbb{H}^2 \times S^1$ (as the union is disjoint)?

Comment: @rowcol: You wrote product, while it should be union. Yes, you should think of the disjoint union (as sets) but the topology is not the one of the disjoint union.